# why does find with an array of ids return an Array whereas `where` with an array of ids returns an ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I do:

```
[29] pry(main)> u=User.where("id in (?)",[1,2])
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
[31] pry(main)>
```

whereas:

```
[33] pry(main)> u=User.find([2,3])
...
[34] pry(main)> u.class
=> Array
[35] pry(main)>
```

I know that both of these are very similar but why doesn't find with an array return an ActiveRecord::Relation. Is there some deep reason? I would have thought that find with an array of id's would return an ActiveRecord::Relation.

thx

Comment: The reason is that `find` returns the actual objects whereas `where` is for finding a relation. This is just a design choice they made in Rails. Sometimes you immediately want the object, and other times you only want a relation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in  rails find calls find_with_ids method which in-turn calls find_some in case you passes an array as argument in it and find_some works as below:-
  result = where(table[primary_key].in(ids)).to_a 
i.e. coverting activerecord:relation object to an array. Hence result provides an array.

You may look at their source codes